# How do I iterate through a table and create a hash for each value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have two tables. One for accounts and another for keywords. I would like to iterate over all of the keywords and store each one in a hash--grouped by the account ID that added the keyword. The code that I have below doesn't add each keyword to the hash. For example, I have an account that has 2 keyword entries. My code skips the first entry and only adds the second entry to the hash.

```
@keyword_hash = {}

@account.each do |key, value|

  @keywords.where(:profile_id => key).each do |keyword|

    @keyword_hash[key] = keyword.entry

  end
end
puts @keyword_hash
```

**How can I modify the above code so that I add each keyword entry for a particular account to the hash?**

I would like to be able to do @keyword_hash[6] and get keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, etc. for that account. Thanks!

Comment: My guess is that you're going about this all wrong and that you want to use a `group_by` query. But, with the information you've provided, it is hard to say.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll look into using group_by or group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@keyword_hash = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }

  @keywords.group_by{ |k| k.profile_id }.each do |key,value|
    @keyword_hash[key] = value.map(&:entry)
    end

  puts @keyword_hash
```

After doing some more research, I found the above solution. I used @jvillian's suggestion about group_by, and I found this [article](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/ruby-cookbook/0596523696/ch05s06.html) that showed me how to initialize the hash.

Comment: Use `@keyword_hash[key] = value.map(&:entry)` instead of nested `each`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I'm curious--is this code better to use because it's more concise? Or are there other reasons too?

Comment: Abusing `each` (which is basically the iteration) with `map` behavior is a code smell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
@keyword_hash = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = [] } 
@account.each do |key, value|
  @keywords.where(:profile_id => key).each do |keyword|
    @keyword_hash[key] << keyword.entry
  end
end
puts @keyword_hash
```

The mistake you are doing is that you are storing a single value against each `key` in your `@keyword_hash` hash. so when your code writes second value against account key, it replaces the previous value instead of adding second one.

Edit: Thank you @mudasobwa for correction regarding shared default value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this returns an empty hash.

Comment: Did you try ```puts keyword.entry``` inside the nested loop to see if is actually going in nested loop? Otherwise, there should be something in @keyword_hash

Comment: If I just call `@keyword_hash` the hash is empty. If I call `@keyword_hash[6]` for example, it returns all of the keywords for every user.

Comment: It seems difficult to identify the problem with limited information. Maybe you could use ```binding.pry``` inside loop to see ```@keyword_hash``` value in each iteration?
https://github.com/pry/pry

Comment: Thank you so much for attempting to help. I really appreciate it!

Comment: This is plain **wrong**. What this code does, it produces a hash with a **shared** between keys array as a default value. Try `h = Hash.new([]); h[:a] << :foo; h[:b] << :bar; h` and you’ll see what I mean. Downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array [keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, etc.] and then add it to hash

**

```
@keyword_hash = {}
@account.each do |key, value|
    arr = []
    @keywords.where(:profile_id => key).each do |keyword|
      arr << keyword.entry
    end
    @keyword_hash[key] = arr
end
puts @keyword_hash
```

**

Comment: You are abusing `each` (`each_with_object` must take place there.) The snippet above is a php code written with some ruby syntax. It is absolutely non-idiomatic.